# How to determine exact contrast ratio

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color-theory, contrast

Because of the recent Web accessibility Law in my region, I need to ensure I'm designing with an appropriate contrast ratio.

WCAG says the value of this ratio is 4.5:1

http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html

How do I figure this out in in Photoshop and Illustrator?

Comment: Non-related to the question, but could you explain/link to an article that explains this law? I've never heard of a law dictating web design before, so I'm quite curious.

Comment: It just came into effect in Ontario Canada. Here's the info: http://www.ellsworthmedia.com/aoda-compliance-impact-website/

Comment: [Link to the actual regulation.](http://www.e-laws.gov.on.ca/html/regs/english/elaws_regs_110191_e.htm#s14s1)  It applies to any organization with more than 50 employees in Ontario and requires them to meet [WCAG 2.0 Level A](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/) on all new websites starting this year, and to convert old websites by 2021.

Comment: Also: [A reference on the WCAG site](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html), which has links to the luminance formula, and calculators.  As far as I can tell, **both the W3 and Adobe use the sRGB colour space for calculating luminance values, so you *should* be able to just use the L values from your colour inspector to determine if the ratio is at least 4.5:1.**

Answer (score 3):

From that page, there is a link to a [contrast calculator](http://www.msfw.com/accessibility/tools/contrastratiocalculator.aspx)

And looking at the source, we can generalize:

```
RsRGB = Red Component  / 255
GsRGB = Green Component / 255
BsRGB = Blue Component  / 255

Calculate luminance
R = is (RsRGB <= 0.03928) then RsRGB/12.92 otherwise ((RsRGB + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4
G = is (GsRGB <= 0.03928) then GsRGB/12.92 otherwise ((GsRGB + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4
B = is (BsRGB <= 0.03928) then BsRGB/12.92 otherwise ((BsRGB + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4

Luminance is (0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B)

getContrastRatio {
L1 = Luminance of color1;
L2 = Luminance of color2;
round((max(L1, L2) + 0.05)/(min(L1, L2) + 0.05)*10)/10;
}
```

The code is embedded in that page, you can bookmark it or you can save it locally in case the page goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I test UI's using a contrast checker app, aptly named "Contrast":

[image: contrast app in action]

You can check not just your files but anything on screen, including other websites — anything on screen!

It's not very practical to measure pure contrast ratios because it's taxing cognitively, numbers have to be compared in the mind like `5.2 > 4.5 ?` so apps invented an abstraction — **scores** based on letters, for example, Contrast Mac app would give "**AA**" for `4.5:1` at least.

https://usecontrast.com/guide

It's a paid Mac app but it doubles as a screen colour picker too:

[image: contrast Mac app]